# c++ referring to a sibling namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

given:

```
namespace root { namespace parent { namespace childa
    class hard_to_get_at{};
}}}

namespace root { namespace parent { namespace childb
    // how do I refer refer to namespace childb relative to the current namespace ?
    ..::hard_to_get_at instance_of_childa_class; // psuedo syntax
}}}
```

Do I need to specify the full path of the namespace? Is there some way around it ?

Comment: I don't think there is a way around that. The best you probably can do is to create short aliases for the outer namespaces.

Comment: If you need to do that, you are misusing namespaces.

Comment: @neil, in terms of dependancy relationship, it is more along the lines of parent-child; they aren't really siblings. They are just siblings in the namespace heirarchy. I was just wondering if it was possible, an alias will probably do the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Next should work :

```
namespace root{
namespace parent{
namespace childb{

// some function where you want to use class hard_to_get_at
void foo()
{
   childa::hard_to_get_at obj;
   // do stuff
}

} // namespace childb
} // namespace parent
} // namespace root
```

Comment: if this is the case, this would be the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I have not tried it, but as far as I remember

```
childa::hard_to_get_at   sibling;
```

should work from within `childb` without the need for defining a namespace alias. this is a property of C++ namespace resolution, which is able to move up the hierarchy of nesting to search for namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a namespace alias in `childb`

```
namespace childa = root::parent::childa;
```

and then

```
childa::hard_to_get_at   sibling;
```

Comment: (+1) whilst this is a common method, VJo's answer is actually what I was looking for :D

Comment: If you are under `root::parent::`, it's always visible as `childa`. No alias needed.

Comment: I would argue that if you really want to fully spell it out, you might as well prefix `root` with `::` to make sure another `root` (nested) does not barge in.