# referring to a cousin namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

i'm having a problem similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6069920/170521), but with one additional depth:

```
namespace root { namespace parent1 { namespace childa {
    class hard_to_get_at{};
}}}

namespace root { namespace parent2 { namespace childb {
    // how do I refer refer to namespace childb relative to the current namespace ?
    void someFunc()
    {
       parent1::childa::hard_to_get_at instance; // does not work
    }
}}}
```

when i tried the above, i get an error

error: 'root::parent2::childb::parent1::childa' has not been declared

i don't understand why this does not work, i get the impression that it should. I really don't want to have to put a using declaration inside the `someFunc` function.

this is happening in g++ 4.5 with c++0x option enabled

Comment: You are probably missing an include in your code, or a whole lot of important details in the question. If the includes are the correct, then you might have multiple namespaces/classes with the same name and the compiler is picking the incorrect one. [Check this](http://ideone.com/bsy8q)

Comment: Your posted code compiles fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing some opening brackets:

```
namespace root { namespace parent1 { namespace childa { // <--- here
    class hard_to_get_at{};
}}}

namespace root { namespace parent2 { namespace childb { // <--- and here
    // how do I refer refer to namespace childb relative to the current namespace ?
    void someFunc()
    {
       parent1::childa::hard_to_get_at instance; // does not work
    }
}}}
```

This is one of the reason indentation is important.

Comment: yes sorry that wasn't intentional, i fixed that on the question

Comment: @lurscher you should probably copy-paste the code, it's probably a different issue.

Comment: the really weird thing is that if i add root:: to the instance declaration, then it compiles, but if i take it out and leave it as in the example it won't

Answer (score 1):

Old question but I had the same problem (or same symptom) and at least in my case the issue was quite tricky so posting in case it helps someone.

Basically, if `parent1` is a namespace inside of `childb` anywhere visible from your TU, the lookup will fail. For example:

```
namespace a { namespace b { namespace c {
class hard_to_get_at {};
}}}

namespace a { namespace d { namespace e {
namespace b {}  // May be in any included '.h'
void f() {
  b::c::hard_to_get_at foo;  // Previous line introduced a::d::e::b which is found before a::b, compiler doesn't backtrack when a::d::e::b::c isn't found.
}
}}}
```

While I can't see all the code to be sure, my guess is this was in fact OP's problem because the error message "`error: 'root::parent2::childb::parent1::childa' has not been declared`" suggests that the compiler found a namespace `root::parent2::childb::parent1` if it's looking for a `childa` there.

By the way, this can be replicated with much less nesting, which makes the issue more obvious:

```
namespace a {
class Foo {};
}

namespace b {
namespace a {}
void f() { a::Foo foo; }  // This will fail because 'a' here is '::b::a'
}
```